# Getting an EACCES error bower init

Tags: node.js, sails.js, bower, bower-install

Trying to run 'bower init' on an assets folder I have on a small project. Trying to learn Sails.js framework but want bower to handle frontend configuration. Stack trace below. Already tried adjusting the access path but no luck. Any pointers in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Trace

```
$ bower init
/Users/lukeduncan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v1.6.2/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:46
            throw err;
                  ^
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/lukeduncan/.config/configstore/insight-bower.json'
You don't have access to this file.

at Error (native)
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:546:18)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:396:15)
at Object.create.all.get (/Users/lukeduncan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v1.6.2/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:26)
at Object.Configstore (/Users/lukeduncan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v1.6.2/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:20:44)
at new Insight (/Users/lukeduncan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v1.6.2/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:37:34)
at ensureInsight (/Users/lukeduncan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v1.6.2/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/util/analytics.js:38:23)
at Object.setup (/Users/lukeduncan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v1.6.2/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/util/analytics.js:55:9)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/lukeduncan/.nvm/versions/io.js/v1.6.2/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower:72:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing with Sails. You have issue with right in your system.

Try to run it with `sudo` command:

```
sudo bower init
```

But, better to fix issues with right to your folders which have the following issue with changing its owner with `chmod` command.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is

```
sudo bower init --allow-root
```